# Converting a PHP mcrypt() call to node's mcrypt

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, encryption, mcrypt

I am trying to recreate an encryption function that we have in our old PHP application into a new Node JS application, using Node's `mycrypt` module.

My goal is the make sure that given the same original string and salt, the PHP script below produces the same encrypted value as the Node script.

---

**PHP**

```
<?php
$string = 'This is my password';
$salt = 'sodiumChloride12';
$encrypted = base64_encode(
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        $salt,
        $string,
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
        mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)
    )
);

echo "Encrypted: $encrypted\n";
```

It produces:

```
Encrypted: iOKEAxaE4vIeWXBem01gHr2wdof7ZO2dld3BuR9l3Nw=
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
var mcrypt = require('mcrypt');
var MCrypt = mcrypt.MCrypt;

// Set algorithm and mode
var rijndaelEcb = new MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'ecb');

// Set up salt and IV
var salt = 'sodiumChloride12';
var iv = rijndaelEcb.generateIv();
rijndaelEcb.open(salt, iv);

/** ENCRYPTION **/
var cipher = rijndaelEcb.encrypt('This is my password');
var cipherConcat = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher]).toString('base64');
console.log('Encrypted: ' + cipherConcat);

/** DECRYPTION **/
// Convert back from base64
var ivAndCipherText = new Buffer(cipherConcat, 'base64');

// Undo concat of IV
var ivSize = rijndaelEcb.getIvSize();
iv = new Buffer(ivSize);
var cipherText = new Buffer(ivAndCipherText.length - ivSize);
ivAndCipherText.copy(iv, 0, 0, ivSize);
ivAndCipherText.copy(cipherText, 0, ivSize);

var plaintext = rijndaelEcb.decrypt(cipherText).toString();
console.log('Decrypted: ' + plaintext);
```

The Node version produces:

```
Encrypted: 834aJoVRxla/fGNACUAVFYjihAMWhOLyHllwXptNYB69sHaH+2TtnZXdwbkfZdzc
Decrypted: This is my password
```

Based on the fact that it decrypted the original phrase, I know the calls are working as expected, but the encrypted output is not the same as in the PHP script. Decryption logic was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18965572/1577649), but I'm more concerned with making the encryption work the same way.

Am I doing something different with the IV in Node than in PHP?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000179/how-to-get-the-same-result-with-node-js-and-php-mcrypt-using-tripledes-encryptio), but it uses the `crypto` module instead of the `mcrypt` module I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing something different with the IV in Node than in PHP?

Hmm. What does the code say?

> `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,`
>
> `var rijndaelEcb = new MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'ecb');`

You're using [ECB mode](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin), which doesn't use an IV. You're actually wasting CPU cycles generating one. Even if you were using CBC mode, `MCRYPT_RAND` is a bad constant to use here.

> `var cipherConcat = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher]).toString('base64');`

You're concatenating an unused IV to your ciphertext, and complaining about an invalid result? The PHP code just returns `cipher` (in Node.js equivalent terms), not a concatenation of `iv` and `cipher`.

---

More importantly, there are some serious cryptography flaws here that need to be addressed, starting with ECB mode as mentioned above:

1. [Do not encrypt passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016), use a password hashing algorithm. [There's a huge difference](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).
2. If you're going to encrypt, [use authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).
3. [Don't use mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).
4. Don't [deploy home-grown crypto protocols into production or encourage other developers to do the same](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it).

Recommended steps:

1. Decrypt your data with PHP, then store passwords [properly](https://secure.php.net/password_hash).
2. If you need encryption for any other purpose, [use a high-level cryptography library](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide), like libsodium.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know much about cryptography and the PHP code was written years ago by someone else, so it's unfortunately not my call to change. As far as the `iv` concatenation in the Node version, I saw it on an example on the module's github page, so I figured that was correct, but removing it all together in the Node version worked out, and makes decryption a lot cleaner.

Comment: I very strongly recommend talking to whomever makes the call and ask them to consider changing the way the encryption is done to make it secure. (If they don't know how, I do consult.)